# Switch-case block inside define keyword in a single logical line in a makefile

Tags: shell, make, newlines

This is the code excerpt from `ghc.mk`, part of Haskell source compilation. 
I find it different, because the author has chosen to write one function block in a single line. Is it a common practice in writing makefiles?

And I like to put `echo` statements in each one of the case handles for debugging, but with the current setup, I am not able to and make  interprets my echo statements as shell commands.

```
define installLibsTo
        $(call INSTALL_DIR,$2)
        for i in $1; do \
                case $$i in \
                  *.a) \
                    $(call INSTALL_DATA,$(INSTALL_OPTS),$$i,$2); \
                    $(RANLIB_CMD) $2/`basename $$i` ;; \
                  *.dll) \
                    $(call INSTALL_PROGRAM,$(INSTALL_OPTS),$$i,$2) ; \
                    $(STRIP_CMD) $2/`basename $$i` ;; \
                  *) \
                  $(call INSTALL_DATA,$(INSTALL_OPTS),$$i,$2); \
                  esac; \
    done
endef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole shell command is on a single logical line because the syntax of makefiles makes it necessary. In a makefile rule, each recipe line is executed in a separate shell instance. Before the parser gets to this point, backslash-newline sequences are removed, so a newline immediately preceded by a backslash doesn't count as a newline. This means that you can write this (I use 8 spaces to stand for a tab):

```
target:
        for x in $^; do \
          somecommand $$x; \
        done
```

and a shell command like this will be executed to build `target`:

```
for x in dependency1 dependency2 dependency3; do           somecommand $x;         done
```

The shell doesn't receive any newline here (which is why the `;` is necessary before `done`).

If you wrote this makefile:

```
target:
        for x in $^; do
          somecommand $$x;
        done
```

then each of `for x in …; do`, `somecommand $x;` and `done` would be executed in a separate shell, which wouldn't work.

The `installLibsTo` variable that you show is a larger example with the same constraints. When it's used, it'll expand to two logical recipe lines, one that executes the command constructed by the call to the `INSTALL_DIR` function and one that executes the for loop.